# Trac 1.0.1 + AccountManagerPlugin + SQLAuthStorePlugin How To Use

Tags: sql, trac

I would like to use SQL plugin in AccountManagerPlugin for Trac 1.0.1, but I could not figure out how to set to use that: http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/SQLAuthStorePlugin

Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated [documentation](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/SQLAuthStorePlugin) on the plugin wiki. If you still have problems installing/using the plugin, please describe in the question what exactly you tried and what happened. Also, check the code, it is really simple.

Comment: Please write to the documentation, what is the accepted parameter list to the "hash_method" and the "sql_read_only" variables.

Comment: Updated documentation. You should really read AccountManagerPlugin documentation too and see how other plugins work.

Comment: The plugin is correct, but the user password change method is not. Password change or when I adding a new user can I get it:

TypeError: set_password() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)

Comment: Maybe there are some version incompatibilities. Compare what arguments are given and which are expected.

Comment: How do I do this the easy way?

Comment: Thank's! I tested the new code, and I found a little bug in it. If set the existing username in the registration the system does not throw an error (example: "The username is already exists!") only replaces the user's password.

Comment: How I understand the [AccountManagerPlugin API](https://trac-hacks.org/svn/accountmanagerplugin/0.11/acct_mgr/api.py), this is so. `set_password` function sets the passwords or create a new account. It might be that there is some bug in AccountManagerPlugin? And that it does not check in registration step for username existence? How does it behave with some other password store?

Comment: I'm going to test some other password store, and send the result.